# nodejs circular module app structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, structure

I have 3 files in the following structure:

1. root.js
2. mod1.js
3. mod2.js

mod1.js and mod2.js are both required / instantiated in root.js and both mod1.js and mod2.js require("root.js"); So that I can perform callbacks to public functions in root.js... The issue I'm having is that const root = require("root.js"); is either {} or empty object in both mod1.js and mod2.js. Especially when I put more code in mod1 and mod2 they both end up being {}

Error screen shot can be seen here:
https://github.com/DarceyLloyd/NodeAppArchitecture/blob/master/issue.png

So the question is, what structure or what code achieves a return of each class/function/object correctly during instantiation? Structural change? I've tested this with a keyup function mapped to the body so that when i press spac eit requires root.js and then runs its getA function just fine, however it only does this at keypress so not during class/function/object instantiation / creation.  Ideas?

All files can be seen here:
https://github.com/DarceyLloyd/NodeAppArchitecture

And for stackoverflow reference:

root.js

````
var Root = function(){
    this.a = -1;
    this.b = -1;

```
const mod1 = require("./mod1.js"); // Runs 2nd?
const mod2 = require("./mod2.js"); // Runs 1st?

function init(){
    this.a = 0;
    this.b = 0;
}

this.incA = function() { this.a++; }
this.incB = function() { this.a++; }
this.getA = function() { return this.a; console.log(a); }
this.getB = function() { return this.b; console.log(b); }

init();
```

}

// Cached output so new only ever gets called once
module.exports = new Root();
````

mod1.js

````
var Mod1 = function(){
    const root = require("./root.js");

```
function init(){
    console.log("Mod1()");
    console.log(root); // result is {}
    //root.incA(); // error incA doesn't exist on object root
}

init();
```

}

// Cached output so new only ever gets called once
module.exports = new Mod1();
````

mod2.js

````
var Mod2 = function(){
    const root = require("./root.js");

```
function init(){
    console.log("Mod2()");
    console.log(root); // result is {}
    //root.incB(); // error incB doesn't exist on object root
}

init();
```

}

// Cached output so new only ever gets called once
module.exports = new Mod2();
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry do disappoint you, but you'll not get correct "instantiation" as long as you're doing circular imports in application. In order to achieve the right behavior you should NOT import in circular way. At the moment you instantiate one object the other is not yet instantiated. I would suggest you the following solution to ensure the object you try to access is instantiated.

```
        // ROOT 
        const mod1 = require("./mod1.js"); // Runs 2nd?
        const mod2 = require("./mod2.js"); // Runs 1st?

        var Root = function(){
            this.a = -1;
            this.b = -1;

            this.init = function(){
                this.a = 0;
                this.b = 0;
            }

            this.incA = function() { this.a++; }
            this.incB = function() { this.a++; }
            this.getA = function() { return this.a; console.log(a); }
            this.getB = function() { return this.b; console.log(b); }
        }


        // Cached output so new only ever gets called once
        module.exports = new Root();

        mod2.init()
        mod1.init()


    // MOD2
    var Mod2 = function(){

        this.init = function() {
            const root = require("./root.js");
            console.log("Mod2()");
            root.init()
            console.log(root); // result is {}
            root.incB(); // error incB doesn't exist on object root
        }
    }

    // Cached output so new only ever gets called once
    module.exports = new Mod2;


    // Mod1
    var Mod1 = function(){
        this.init = function() {
            const root = require("./root.js");
            root.init()
            console.log("Mod1()");
            console.log(root); // result is {}
            root.incA(); // error incA doesn't exist on object root
        }
    }

    // Cached output so new only ever gets called once
    module.exports = new Mod1;
```

Comment: There's a double run of each mod1 and mod2 then and I seem to loose, the singleton / cached require behaviour with that setup... I've pushed 0.0.3 to github.

Comment: Updated github to 0.0.4, this version achieves what I want but requires passing root via the instantiation method within the root class. Not ideal as I was looking for a singleton kind of way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Usually circular dependencies means a lack of architecture, having a coupling system, so, it's always good avoid circular dependencies. If module A use module B and module B use module A (A -> B, B -> A) then this could be the same module or even an option is trying to split in more smaller functionalities to import just the minimum ones.
The proposed solution by @Vitiok it's ok, require the module in an init function. Keep in mind require is sync and if you have a web app this could freeze your cpu if you are hitting this solution too many times.

My advice: If you want to avoid problems really hard to debug, don't create circular dependencies.

Comment: I am thinking in the lines of AS3, C#, Java etc... I think I'm going to need to create some kind of instance check in each function before using root functions. I could put a timer in and allow each root instantiated component to give 1/4 a second before trying to instantiate root. Maybe make a model and have that do this and request all variables via that.. but will bring me back to this issue again trying to require a core model in every module i make... I need an example of how this is done correctly with 3 classes root, mod1, mod2 etc...  or pass root at instantiation.

Comment: Exactly, that case is preferable, you can pass to the constructor of mod1 / mod2 the root app (so, injecting the dependencies)